# Linear Regression with Dates

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-algebra

I have a very large data set with Date and value. Can I use Linear Regression with date and value to get the prediction Formula.

I have Date and utilization value.
I can convert date to a numerical value and get the Prediction formula but I think that will not work .

Can you please help me how to handle this use case ? what is the Best Machine learning technique to use? I prefer Linear regression but not sure how to use.

Comment: I don't see a good reason why any distance-preserving transformation would not work. E.g. date to unix-timestamp, then subtracting the lowest  one from all for some kind of centering.

Comment: so you mean if I have 1/1/2008 convert that to uniq time stamp and make it 0 as that is my starting value

Comment: Yes, but the others need to be subtracted too. It's like ```vector(x0, x1, ...)
 - x0``` (vector-subtract; x0, x1 ordered from low to high!). (it's also only for numerical-robustness in regards to the underlying optimization-algorithm, they don't like very small or very big numbers; maybe not necessary; more necessary for big-data algorithms like SGD)

Comment: so you mean if 1/1/2008 is 1, 1/2/2008 as 2?

Comment: Did you even google [unix-timestamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)? :-) It looks like you did not. The **unit** is not days! I only mentioned these, because it's inbuilt in all time-based libs so this transform in both directions does not need to be done manually! (you can use days too depending on your data)

Comment: :) yes I did . I get that value. epoc value..my question is should I use that value as is (or) should I make it 0 which is better..I am planning to keep every day 5PM time so that they are equally distributed.

Comment: I don't get your problem. Every linear transform is equally good in terms of math. The centering i mentioned is just to be nice to the optimizer (and in regards to SGD as potential optimizer you might also want to center so that the mean is 0).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159819/discussion-between-user826407-and-sascha).

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you convert the date to a number. If you just pick a date that is smaller but close to the minimum possible value of the date field and do "days since" that base date you should be fine.

You can also consider (experiment) picking a base date that is close to the median value of the date field (in which case you'll have both positive and negative values).

Picking a date far in the past is generally not a good idea (for the obvious reason)...

Comment: Thank you for reply. so 1) we can use Linear regression for Date? 2) I have date from Jan 31st  2008 what should I start the value with?

Comment: 1 - yes, most definitely... 2 - depends on the shape of your data, so experiment, I'd first try with 1/1/2008 and something like 1/1/2013

Comment: Thank you so can you please tell me when you say try 1/1/2008 mean? I did not get that . Can you please help me how should I keep the date value as? should I keep it as 1?

Comment: add a new field with the datediff (days since) 1/1/2008